# how to rename default package in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to rename default package in eclipse

[image]

I want to rename (default package) and then extends it in to another class in 
  different package ?

Comment: Try to right-click -> Refactor -> Rename .

Comment: not working for default package but others